# Android: how to set the path for saving files etc like in windows we write c:/someting/...what will I do in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to record voice and save it in a file. For this I have to give a path to save the file, but I don't know how will I set the path...I have recently started working on android phone. In windows we set path like a drive e.g. C:/folder/folder....in android phone what will be my root? Where can I save an audio file? Write now I am working on emulator...Will the path be same for both emulator and phone?

Comment: Got through this example you may get some idea [https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-file-to-sd-card](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-file-to-sd-card)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we can create file like this in `SD card`

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myDir = new File(root + "/folder");    
myDir.mkdirs();    
String fname = "file";
File file = new File (myDir, fname);
```

file is the path of file where you stored.

and add this `Permission` in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
_path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/RECORDS/";
            //                        ||                       || 
            //                        VV                       VV 
            //                  storage path              folder name 
fileName =  String.format("filename.mp3");
File file = new File(_path, fileName);
try {
    file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Save your file in Sdcard.

```
    File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String cardName = path.getName();
    path=cardName+"/mypathname/file_name.mp3";
```

It is also possible in emulator. create sdcard , when you create emulator.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Uri outputFileUri;

File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

     + File.separator + "myDir" + File.separator);

   root.mkdirs();

   sdImageMainDirectory = new Filenter code here(root, "myPicName.jpg");

   outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
```